# Push Notifications sent to iOS always fail

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios, push-notification

I am integrating the MarketingCloudSDK v7.5.0 in a iOS app. I configured the SDK for
receiving push notifications and I also configured the APNs key p8 in Salesforce page.

When I send a push from MobilePush page, the push notification always fails as you can see in the following screenshot.

[image]

How can I get the reason of the error? Why the push notification failed to be sent?

Thanks